# Powershell Script outputs are merged instead of separated individually

Tags: powershell

I made this script to ping a computer name and if it's pingable, to return the username of the logged on user and if the user of the script so desires, a list of all the installed programs and a list of the installed printers the user is using.

When I run the script it returns the username and requires the users' input if they want to see the installed programs, the user answers Y or N. It asks the user afterwards if they want to the list of printers.
The script then gives an output of both the list of programs & printers as one answer.

My problem is that I would like the script to ask if the user wants the programs list, then to output the programs list, then prompt if the user wants the printers list, then output the printer list.

I have no idea how to go about this and have searched and experimented and have found no solution.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated  :)

Apologies for the long post

```
# This script shows who is currently logged on to a machine

$PCNAME = Read-Host "Please enter computer name"

Write-Host "Pinging computer name..."

# If the computer responds to ping then the user name will be displayed

If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $PCNAME -Quiet)

    {
    $User = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $PCNAME | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName
    $Time = Get-Date -DisplayHint Time


                Write-Host ""
     $CurUser = Write-Host "The current user logged in to $PCNAME is $User at $Time" -ForegroundColor Green
                Write-Host ""
    }

        #PROGRAMS

    $Programs = Read-Host "Would you like to see what programs $User has installed? Enter Y or N"


        If ($Programs -eq "Y") {
                Write-Host ""
                Write-Host "Retrieving list of installed programs..."
                Write-Host ""

        Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $PCNAME -Class Win32_Product | sort-object Name | select Name
                            }

        ElseIf ($Programs -ne "Y" -and $Programs -eq "N") {
                Write-Host ""
                Write-Host "Will not retrieve list of installed programs."
                                                    }


    #PRINTERS

$Printers = Read-Host "Would you like to see the pinters that $User is using? Enter Y or N"

    If ($Printers -eq "Y") {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Getting printers..."
        Write-Host ""


# Collect port names and host addresses into hash table
$hostAddresses = @{}
Get-WmiObject Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort -ComputerName $PCNAME | ForEach-Object {
  $hostAddresses.Add($_.Name, $_.HostAddress)
}

Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $PCNAME | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "Name" = $_.Name
    "DriverName" = $_.DriverName
    "HostAddress" = $hostAddresses[$_.PortName]
  }
}

}

    ElseIf ($Printers -ne "Y" -and $Printers -eq "N") {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Could not get printers"
        Write-Host ""
        }




 Else  
    {
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Could not ping $PCNAME at $Time" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
    }


Write-Host ""
#$EndPrompt = ( Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to finish" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's better ways of doing this overall, but the simplest way to add this is:

```
        #PROGRAMS

    $Programs = Read-Host "Would you like to see what programs $User has installed? Enter Y or N"


        If ($Programs -eq "Y") {
                Write-Host ""
                Write-Host "Retrieving list of installed programs..."
                Write-Host ""

        $Installed = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $PCNAME -Class Win32_Product | sort-object Name | select Name
        $Installed | Out-Host
                            }

        ElseIf ($Programs -ne "Y" -and $Programs -eq "N") {
                Write-Host ""
                Write-Host "Will not retrieve list of installed programs."
                                                    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
I'm quite new to PowerShell, sorry if the script was a tad messy